# ios UIBarButtonItem with UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose showing red button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add a UIBarButtonItem with the style of UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose. According to the apple docs it should display a compose icon that consists of a square outline. When I use the following code it just displays a red button. Does the icon only work if the uibarbuttonitem if placed inside of a UIToolBar and not a navigation bar.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:nil
                                          style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose
                                          target:self
                                          action:@selector(tweetPressed:)] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the button incorrectly. You need to use the proper `init...` method.

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose target:self action:@selector(tweetPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn;
[btn release];
```

Look at the docs for the `init...` method you used. Look at what type should be passed for the `style` parameter and look at what the valid values are.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. This works great. I'm not sure how I missed this.