# UIBarButtonItem image not displayed but a red square is instead

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am trying to display a right arrow in a cell (the way Apple does) using an image and UIBarButtonItem class. The problem is that instead of the image displayed there is a red square that is the same size as the image. I tried to change the image using another one and I got another red square that has the same size (and this time rounded corners) as the other image.

My code below:

```
UIImage *arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];

UIBarButtonItem *runItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:arrowImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered handler:^(id sender) {

    [self pushListWithID:[(DIDList *)_fetcher.fetchedObjects[indexPath.row] idValue] runMode:NO];

}];

[(UIToolbar *)cell.accessoryView setItems:@[runItem]];
```

I checked this but it did not really help [ios UIBarButtonItem with UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose showing red button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443057/ios-uibarbuttonitem-with-uibarbuttonsystemitemcompose-showing-red-button)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the size of the image and resolution so that it perfectly fits your button.
I doubt that your image is bigger than actual size to be fitted in the barButton

Comment: I tried it with a 40 x 40 pixels image (which is required iOS Retina devices) and after with a 20 x 20 pixels one... None of them solved the issue...

Comment: Try to add UIButton instead of UIBarButton.

Comment: I think it would be simpler to go directly with UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator. Any idea how I could adapt my code to use this instead of an image?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't relevant to your specific problem, but I ran into a similar issue and would like to pass my solution on to others. When I was loading a JPEG of the hamburger icon, I was getting a red square. I tried resizing it to 20 x 20 and that didn't help. If I had it in its original form, the 512 x 512 took up a lot of the screen.

I eventually found a PNG version of the image (http://www.appdesignvault.com/ios-7-button-design/) and that worked perfectly. So file format may be relevant, but you are already using a PNG, so that isn't true for your case.